# Rearrange the lines which contains X

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a csv file which contains results like

"404|491","65640","70419"

"402|493","65663","70933"

"402|493","65663","0"

"402|493","65663","70555"

I want to make a loop that finds the lines which has EXACTLY "0" on the third column and put it into the first line, delete the blank so the result will be like the bottom. I dont have any column which can be "0" except for the third column if it helps.

"402|493","65663","0"

"404|491","65640","70419"

"402|493","65663","70933"

"402|493","65663","70555"

I'm very newbie to coding so any help or guidance would help me. Thank you

Comment: Please post your first try. It is very important so people can help you

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: There is no native way for a batch file to sort a comma delimited file. You would be better off writing an Excel VBA macro to import the file, sort it and then output the file again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements are very imprecise, which can have a major impact on potential solutions.

For example:

- Does every row have 3 columns?
- Can a column value contain a comma?
- Can a line end with `,"0"` that is not in the 3rd column?

Below is a very fast and simple solution that makes the following assumptions

- Every line is terminated by \r\n (Carriage Return, LineFeed)
- If a line ends with `,"0"`, then it is always in the 3rd column.

I use FINDSTR to extract only lines that end with `,"0"`.
Then I use a 2nd FINDSTR to extract lines that *don't* end with `,"0"`.

```
@echo off
findstr ",\"0\"$" test.csv >test.csv.new
findstr /v ",\"0\"$" test.csv >>test.csv.new
move /y test.txt.new test.csv >nul
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use PowerShell.

```
Import-Csv '.\rearrange.csv' -Header f1,f2,f3 | Sort-Object f3 | Export-Csv rearrange-out.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

If you want to strip the header record off, this will work.

```
Get-Content '.\rearrange-out.csv' | Select-Object -Skip 1
```

Comment: @AlperKöse - If this works well for you, please mark it as the answer. That is how Stack Overflow works.